# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data

I have the following query:

```
@Query(nativeQuery =true,value= "update inv_goods_line_item set 
a_poinv_portfolio ='' where p_inv_goods = :id")
```

in spring hibernate as a native query.

Then I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

I really don't understand the mistake in this query. The same query in oracle is working fine.

Comment: Please, enable the SQL log and add generated SQL to your question.

Comment: @Aleksej  Thanks.Yes my id is string.That might be the problem.

Comment: @Aleksej but in that case will I get this error ?

Comment: @Aleksej No that is not the issue here.

Comment: But it is saying syntax error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113016/discussion-between-psr-and-aleksej).

Comment: Post the annotated method signature

Comment: Please put a space in between single quotes, then try